# Hub Docker - nginx vulnerabilities listed

Tags: security

While researching about Docker Container with `nginx`, it caught my attention that `Ubuntu` still offers version 1.18 while the last stable version is 1.24.

When I was looking at Hub Docker for other versions available, I did notice the existence of several vulnerabilities listed. In special, version 1.18 has 4C and 15H results, and it really surprised me.

How should I deal with these vulnerabilities? In your projects, how do you manage to check these vulnerabilities outside your code?